# "The previous instance of the timer job [...] is still running, so the current instance will be skipped. "

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, logs

The log files in our SharePoint 2007 farm are growing insanely large for about one hour every day. They are fills with these messages:

> 03/15/2016 08:44:56.92    OWSTIMER.EXE (0x14EC)                       0x10B4  Windows SharePoint Services     Timer                           5uuf    Monitorable The previous instance of the timer job 'Quick Profile Synchronization', id '{3216FF45-CAE0-4CBC-A80F-56DBCAB2CAB8}' for service '{0EEDB9E3-3C61-4F44-AF45-9D7E3554CC9D}' is still running, so the current instance will be skipped.  Consider increasing the interval between jobs.

In the example above it is the Quick Profile Synchronization that is pointed out, but we get the same messages for loads of different timer jobs, such as Variations Propagate Site Job Definition, Scheduled Unpublish, Application Server Timer Job, Config Refresh, etc...

I cleared the configuration cache, as suggested in this blog post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/josrod/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache, but it had no effect.

I know that I could always change the log settings so we don't get this messages, but that's just dealing with the symptoms, not the problem.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://johngotsell.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/sharepoint-errors-previous-instance-of-timer-job-still-running/ An issue related with security update in Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that only hides the problem. It decreases the log files, but it doesn't solve the problem.